# Lower bound of the zeros of the zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am currently reading [Riemann Zeta Function by Katsuraba and Voronin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3110131706)

**Theorem :** Let $\rho_n = \beta_n + \gamma_n,$ where $1,2,\dots$ be all complex zeros of $\zeta(s)$, and let $T \ge 2$. Then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+(T-\gamma_n)} \leq c \log T.$$
[image]

**Question:** Can someone explain why the author used $\frac{1}{2}$, here instead of $1$? ($\text{Re} \frac{1}{s-\rho_n} \ge \frac{0.5}{1+(T-\gamma_n)^2}$.) Is there any intuition why $1/2$ will work better here? Or is this just a typo?.

Comment: why does it matter?

Comment: It does not matter as long as the coefficient is some positive number

Comment: I just wanna know why Katsuraba uses $1/2$ instead of $1$ maybe there is something that i'm not getting.